# Dynamic react hooks to trigger button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic

I have a react app which getting a data from the server, and I want to add each data a state. Let's see my design app :

[image]

NB : the red line are each data that I have requested (the white row is the data attribute).

So each data should be able to be clicked and have own state to show the `proposal` and `laporan akhir` attribute. I'm using React hooks, so how am I supposed to do that?

this is my code so far :

```js
function RekapAngkatan({
  auth,
  getProposalRecapByYear,
  getReportRecapByYear,
  posts,
  StickyNav
}) {
  const postingan = posts.posts
  const blankPanduan = {id: "", value: false};  
  const [panduan, setPanduan] = React.useState([{...blankPanduan.value}])
  let content;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
      // Server request
      const getProposals = async () => await getProposalRecapByYear()
      const getReports = async () => await getReportRecapByYear()

      getProposals()
      getReports()
    }
  }, [auth])

if (loading) {
  content = <Loading />
} else {
  // trying to dynamically setState
  setPanduan([
      ...panduan,
      {
        id: postingan.data.length,
        value: false
      }
    ])


  content = postingan.data.map((post, i) => {
    <Section bg="transparent" margin="0 1.5em" padding="0 2em" key={i}>
          <div className="info-color">
            {post.value}
            <FakeButton
              bg="#8C489F"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => setPanduan([...panduan, {...!blankPanduan}])}
            >
              Caret Down
            </FakeButton>

           {/* showing attributes*/}
           <Attribute show={panduan.value}>
             {post.amount}
           </Attribute>
          </div>
    </Section>

   })
  }
  return content
}
```

Comment: Create an array state value called `activeItems`. When you click on a section, push the iterator (`i`) of the section into the activeItems array. Inside your map, you can check if the section is open if the iterator is inside the activeItems

Comment: How do I set the length of the `activeItems` state?